# What would cause my mysqli connect function to fail?

Tags: php, get, mysqli

I have just discovered mysql and mysqli, so I'm really a beginner here.
I have a function that I'm using (from an included php file) with all of the variables to connect to the server, OO style. It works like a charm for the home page, but I have a page (using a get request from a form) that tries to use the function and fails. Here is the function:

```
function connect(){
        $servername = "";
        $dbusername = "";
        $dbpassword = "";
        $dbname = "";
        $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
        if($mysqli->connect_errno){
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        return $mysqli;
}
```

Is there something about the GET request that's stopping it? Is this inappropriate practice? I've been sorting through the docs, but I'm seriously confused. Here is the code I'm using to call the function:

```
include_once '/tools/config.php';#This is the file the function is in
                                 #(I even copied the text from the working file) 
$mysql = connect();
```

My debugging amounts to commenting out individual lines until it works. Might there be a better way? Thank you.

Comment: let me know if you need any other code shown.

Comment: What error message do you get specifically?

Comment: PHP doesn't care how you invoked a script when it comes time to connect to mysql, unless you're using some data passed to the script as part of the connection process. You're not using any $_GET data in your connect call, so it's NOT a problem with using _GET.

Comment: You didn't tell us the result of this code. How does it fail? Where are you using the GET? Are you really trying with empty string data?

Comment: That was stupid. My problem was that the include link pointed to the wrong directory. Works great now.

Comment: Is there a way to get error messages if your php fails?

Comment: turn on error reporting, log and\or show error messages.

Comment: would that be in the php.ini file?

Comment: Yes, you can set display_errors to 1 in php.ini or you can use ini_set() to turn it on for individual pages.

Comment: I don't really want to accept my answer, so if anyone wants to claim it, put an answer down, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the syntax of this function. The problem was in my include statement. Thank you all for your help.